# How to mock a method that returns a file

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

In my unit testing, I want to mock a method which returns a file in java. How do I mock a method that returns a file in java? The code looks something along the lines of

```
    private File baseDirectory;
    private String fileName;
    private File file;

public File getFile(String userName, String hostName)
            throws VerifyException, IOException {
        hostName = "/" + hostName;
        userName = "/" + userName;
        baseDirectory = new File(hostName, userName);
        if (!baseDirectory.exists()) {
            baseDirectory.mkdirs();
        }
        fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmssSSS'.txt'").format(new Date());
        file = new File(baseDirectory, fileName);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: `File f =new File("xyz"); return f`

Comment: @UmaKanth What if `"xyz"` is environment dependent?

Answer (score -1):

Since you mentioned Mockito - here's a quick test I came up with. Done using Mockito Annotations.

```
@Mock
FileFetcher fileFetcher;

@InjectMocks
ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

@Before
public void init(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
@Test
public void testGetFile() throws VerifyException, IOException {
    //set expectations
    Mockito.when(fileFetcher.getFile(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(getTestFile());
    //call
    classUnderTest.getFileTest();
    //verify
    Mockito.verify(fileFetcher, Mockito.times(1));
}

private File getTestFile() {
    return null;
}
```